# Teenagers recruited for a fight, have to find armour made of gold/silver alloy

Tags: story-identification

It was a Power Rangers-like show, set in present day or thereabouts, with a number of teenagers recruited by someone/something to fight something.

They first had to locate ancient (magical?) suits of armour for each member made of a gold/silver alloy and hidden somewhere in the world.  I believe when they were being told this, they were shown holograms (or something) of the armours in question, though I don't remember what they looked like.  I think I only ever saw the one episode, and it was probably the first or second one.

<s>It was probably shown on YTV</s>  in Canada in the mid-to-late 90s.  Unless [Wikipedia's listing of previous YTV shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_YTV) is incomplete, it doesn't seem to be there.

<s>Could also have been Sci-fi Channel.</s>  [Doesn't seem to be there either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Syfy_programs#Past_programs).

Comment: Do you have any memory of the teenagers? Was it the typical mixture of races? Did the show seem to be dubbed?

Comment: @phantom42 - I think they might have been all white males and the leader might have been blond, but I have a _very_ low degree of certainty and might be getting this crossed with something else.  I also don't think it was dubbed.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [The Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mystic_Knights_of_Tir_Na_Nog), or is the time period wrong?

In [Episode 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA4bS2TImeg), about 4 minutes in, the teenage Knights are told:

> Ages ago, long before the little people, the ancient ones **turned silver and gold into magical armor...**

(Emphasis added)

Immediately after they are shown mini "holograms" of the ancient Knights in that armor, but it done by the magic of the faerie king speaking to the young Knights, not by technology.

As you can see in the episode guide on Wikipedia, the Knights then spend the next several episode finding their armor (usually gained by defeating an guardian foe).

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, Why you think its a match.

Comment: No.  I'm pretty sure it was set in approximately present day.  By "power rangers", I was meaning the original Mighty Morphing series.

Comment: I suggested edits to this answer that support it as correct. The main characters are specifically told in episode 3 that they need to find armor made from gold and silver and immediately after are shown "holograms" of that armor. I'm positive that this *is* the correct answer, and any details about it that the OP doesn't agree with would be because he `might be getting this crossed with something else`, in his own words. There's simply not enough YA live action shows from the 90s to open up the possibility of a different answer, especially when the OP already says he's checked them off.